# ERROR 1452 (23000): cannot add or update a child row.

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

what could be the problem here?help me please :)
and please explain hehe thanks! :)

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: The error message gave you the reason.

Comment: well, i really don't understand what the error is saying :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you have set `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on your table `category`.

```
Insert into ads values (1, 'pd');        // successful
DELETE from ads                          // successful
INSERT INTO category VALUES (1,1,'a');   // failed!
```

the third query failed because value for `adid` which is `1` doesn't exist anymore on table category. In other words, the value for `adid` on table category is depended on the values for `ID` on table `ads`.

Comment: you mean, i have to insert record on ads first before on category?

Comment: @SkyScraper exactly. value for `adid` you want to insert or update must exist first on ads table.

Answer (score 0):

Given your schema, you can only insert a `category` for an `ads` that already exists.